# Remembering a Fighting Fantasy style book, with nothing but illustrations

Tags: story-identification, books

When I was younger and still in school I used to play Fighting Fantasy books (and the like). Now I'm an older geek - I want to find my favourite one.

It had bearly any words and was almost all illustrations of sections of a dungeon in a first person view. Each page you turned to showed you the next step of the dungeon. I think you only had to escape...?

Anyway, I BELIEVE that the books were called "Black Knight" and "White Knight". I also THINK you can play them two player?!

Any/all help would be lovely!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "Combat Heroes" series by Joe Dever; you're thinking of "Black Baron" and "White Warlord", the first two in the series.

The nice folks at Project Aon have them available online (with approval from the author): http://www.projectaon.org/en/Main/BlackBaron

Comment: Years.. Years I've looked for this! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

It's the [Combat Heroes](http://www.goodreads.com/series/67762-combat-heroes) series by Joe Dever. The books are [Black Baron](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1272709.Black_Baron) and [White Warlord](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4017215-white-warlord).